# Set ImageView Height 50% Of That's Width

Tags: java, android, imageview

I want to set ImageView height 50% of that's width.
how I can do it?
For example if ImageView's width equals 200dp I want to that's height equals 100dp.

I tried like this, but it's not working.

```
int img_width = cover_img.getLayoutParams().width;
        int img_height = img_width/2;
        cover_img.getLayoutParams().width = img_width;
        cover_img.getLayoutParams().height = img_height;
        cover_img.requestLayout();
```

Please help me

UPDATE:
I wrote and I used this class to do it, that's simple, easy and fast way to set ImageView height 50% of that's width.

```
public class RectImage extends ImageView
{
    public RectImage(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public RectImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RectImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    public RectImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        final int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, widthSize/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: View sizes are defined after the onDraw phase. Where did you try your code?

Comment: I trying in my activity.

Comment: But in wich method? onCreate/onResume/...?

Comment: onCreate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set ratio in xml if use "Constraint layout"

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cover_img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Or set by programmatically like your sample code.

```
//Your layout param type
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams lpm =  cover_img.getLayoutParams();
    int width = lpm.width;
    int height =width/2;
    lpm.height = height;
    cover_img.setLayoutParams(lpm);
    cover_img.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this given below

```
int img_width = cover_img.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        int img_height = img_width/2;
        cover_img.getLayoutParams().width = img_width;
        cover_img.getLayoutParams().height = img_height;
        cover_img.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ConstraintLayout` as the root, you can do the below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            >

           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:0.50"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It's mainly around `layout_constraintDimensionRatio` This would automatically achieve what you want, probably would be the easiest as well.

Of course, please position your view as you like, and disregard the constraint guidelines here, I just put them there for a full example.